# Weighted sum of a column in Polars dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a Polars dataframe and I want to calculate a weighted sum of a particular column and the weights is just the positive integer sequence, e.g., 1, 2, 3, ...

For example, assume I have the following dataframe.

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 6, 7, 5]})
```

The result I want is

```
218 (= 2*1 + 4*2 + 2*3 + 1*4 + ... + 7*9 + 5*10)
```

**How can I achieve this by using only general polars expressions?** (The reason I want to use just polars expressions to solve the problem is for speed considerations)

*Note: The example is just a simple example where there are just 10 numbers there, but in general, the dataframe height can be any positive number.*

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such weighted sum can be calculated using dot product (`.dot()` method). To generate range (weights) from 1 to n, you can use `pl.arange(1, n+1)`.

If you just need to calculate result of weighted sum:

```py
df.select(
    pl.col("a").dot(pl.arange(1, pl.count()+1))
) #.item() - to get value (218)
```

Keep dataframe

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("a").dot(pl.arange(1, pl.count()+1)).alias("weighted_sum")
)
```

```
┌─────┬──────────────┐
│ a   ┆ weighted_sum │
│ --- ┆ ---          │
│ i64 ┆ i64          │
╞═════╪══════════════╡
│ 2   ┆ 218          │
│ 4   ┆ 218          │
│ ... ┆ ...          │
│ 3   ┆ 218          │
│ 5   ┆ 218          │
└─────┴──────────────┘
```

In `groupby` context

```py
df.groupby("some_cat_col", maintain_order=True).agg([
    pl.col("a").dot(pl.arange(1, pl.count()+1))
])
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much. One follow-up, what if I want to do the dot product in the groupby context? How can get n? Is pl.col("a").count() one way to go?

Comment: Yes. Using `pl.count()` will be a good solution.

Comment: Could you adapt your answer to use `pl.count`? It is more ideomatic.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to dot the series a with the index + 1

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 6, 7, 5]})

print(df["a"].dot(df.index+1))
```

Alternatively, you can use the **__matmul__** operator @

```
print(df["a"] @ (df.index + 1))
```